Tailwind translate layout
I used this code with tailwind
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 w-64 space-x-1 bg-black p-2 rounded-xl">
      <div class="relative z-0 bg-black">
        <div class="relative z-20 grid-rows-3">
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-white h-20 rounded-xl"></div>
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-black h-1"></div>
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-white h-20 rounded-xl"></div>
          <div class="absolute z-20 bottom-1/2 translate-y-1/2 right-1/2 translate-x-1/2 text-[200px]">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="relative z-0 bg-black">
        <div class="relative z-20 grid-rows-3">
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-white h-20 rounded-xl"></div>
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-black h-1"></div>
          <div class="relative z-10 bg-white h-20 rounded-xl"></div>
          <div class="absolute z-20 bottom-1/2 translate-y-1/2 right-1/2 translate-x-1/2 text-[200px]">6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

the output looks like this:

Left is chrome right is firefox. Can please someone explain me why it looks different (wrong) in firefox?
Many thanks

Does the issue exist when the code is isolated?  I personally don't see any difference between the two browsers using just the code given: https://play.tailwindcss.com/yQ2I5x6gMN Is there any other CSS being applied outside of the tailwind classes?
